# How to use console view in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I just started using RCP to write Java-based applications. I am trying to add a console view in my app, and output info of log4j to the console. Now it works. But there is a problem, it cannot perform as eclipse witch output once per line, but output all info after the method finish.

```
Object[] elements = tableViewer.getCheckedElements();
    if(elements.length > 0){
        for(Object ele : elements){
            File file = (File) ele;
            logger.info("log4j处理目录" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            MessageConsoleStream stream = ConsoleFactory.getConsole().newMessageStream();
            stream.println("println处理目录" + file.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried use stream.println() stream.flush(), but it does not work.
It is my first time questing on stackoverflow. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the User Interface Thread will block the entire UI and nothing will happen. Never do this.

If you want to do something once a second use the `timerExec` method of `Display` to run code.

Something like:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000, new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     // TODO output one item to the log

     // TODO if need to run again call
     Display.getDefault().timerExec(1000, this);
   }
});
```

The JavaDoc for `MessageConsoleStream` says:

> Clients should avoid writing large amounts of output to this stream in
>   the UI thread. The console needs to process the output in the UI
>   thread and if the client hogs the UI thread writing output to the
>   console, the console will not be able to process the output.

So you must **not** loop constantly outputting to the stream without letting other code in the UI thread run.

Comment: Thanks. But you take look at this.![][https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-2.jpg]<img src="https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-3.jpg" width="660"><img src="https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-1.jpg" width="660">

Comment: If you have an image or something to add edit your question.

Comment: Sorry I really do not know how to insert images. I upload three images.https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-2.jpg   https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-3.jpg   https://github.com/tsingheng/shangtech-framework/blob/3.0.0/image-1.jpg

Comment: The code in the images is doing the same thing - hogging the UI thread. You will only get output when you let other things in the UI thread run.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use  a Job to run the loop. It works.